# Code for TextBox1_Lostfocus starts running before the text box "loses focus"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text box and a combo box in an excel sheet that are dependent on each other. Sometimes the code for the text box starts running before it should be, after inputting just one character instead of waiting until I click out of it, ending up with an error result. See Below code and a screenshot of the textbox properties.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Lostfocus()

    Range("p5").Value = TextBox1.Value
    With Range("P5")
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Range("Q5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[ShevgenII.xlsb]Sheet1!R1C1:R60C2,2,FALSE),""Error"")"


End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 
 On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Calculator").Range("q5").Copy
    Sheets("Calculator").Range("q5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Calculator").Range("P5").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]=""Fee Class"",""Enter"",LEFT(RC[1],3))"
    TextBox1.Value = Range("P5")
    
    Sheets("Calculator").Range("A1").Copy
    Sheets("Calculator").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    

End Sub
```

I know my code is amateurish, I'm still learning...

The problem happens when for example I want to enter the numbers "524" but I only got to enter "5" the Vlookup will return an error because there is no match for "5".
Note that "q5" is the linked cell for the combo-box, so changes to the textbox automatically trigger the combo-box code.
[image: Textbox Properties]

Comment: That lower case "f" is suspicious "Lostfocus". Do you have any other subs with that name?

Comment: this is what vba gave me from the dropdown menu of text box events

Comment: In a previous version of this excel file I also had this code on the same codesheet:

 ```Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
End Sub```

I added it back and now its not giving me this problem. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would expect the Change event to cause the behaviour mentioned in your question.

Comment: Right, thats why I initially removed it when I was cleaning up all the extra code before publishing this document form my teammates. It was just a blank procedure....

Comment: Open a new workbook, add the textbox and the lostfocus code from the dropdown (the event need only contain e.g. a single msgbox line) and see if that works. The code should only fire when you move focus from the textbox, not when you press a key.

Comment: Surprise! I copied the text box, combo-box and code for both (remember I need them to work together); if the Change event was commented out the Lostfocus event ran after just one character entered, if it was active the code worked as expected. Seems like that "blank" procedure kind of told excel not to do anything just from a change, rather it should wait till it lost focus...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a previous version of this excel file I also had this code on the same codesheet:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change() 
End Sub
```

I added it back now and its working fine.

I initially removed it when I was cleaning up all the extra code before publishing this document for my teammates; which is when I started having the above issue. However it seems like its not extra even though it is a blank procedure. I guess it is kind of telling VBA not to do anything just from a change, rather it should wait till the text box lost focus.